# Declare object on heap and then passing it by reference?

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, pass-by-reference

If I was to declare an object on the heap like so:

```
X* x = new X();
func(?);

void func(X& x);
```

How can I pass `x` in to `func()` so that `func()` can receive a reference to `x` (and not a pointer)?

Comment: do you want more than the two answers here? It looks to me like you know how to ask but have somehow forgotten how to accept. I suggest a review of all your questions is in order.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to dereference it like so:`func(*x)`

Answer (score 3):

De-reference the pointer and pass it like this:

```
func(*x);
```

Your function must be passed something of type X. The fact that the object is *passed* by reference is passed doesn't change how you call it. Since x has type X* you need to de-reference x in order to get something of type X.

To illustrate, suppose you had

```
void func1(X& x);
void func2(const X& x);
void func3(X x);
void func4(const X x);
```

For each case you would call the functions in identical fashion.